# 自作のライブラリをインポートしているコードをjestでテストするとエラーが発生します。

Tags: next.js, jestjs

自作のライブラリをインポートしているコードをjestでテストするとエラーが発生します。

jest以外の処理は成功しているのですが、どうすればテストを成功させることができるのでしょうか。

```
FAIL  src/pages/e2e.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'components/layout/Layout' from 'src/pages/index.tsx'

    Require stack:
      src/pages/index.tsx
      src/pages/e2e.spec.tsx

    > 1 | import { Layout } from 'components/layout/Layout'
        | ^


      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/index.tsx:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/e2e.spec.tsx:7:1)
```

## try

commnad: npm test

code

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import { Layout } from 'components/layout/Layout'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { Header } from 'components/parts/common/header'
import { useTranslationText } from 'locale'
import Home from './index'

describe('Home', () => {
  it('should display search results', async () => {
    // Render the Home component
    render(<Home />)

    // Search for a new keyword
    const searchInput = screen.getByRole('textbox')
    userEvent.clear(searchInput)
    userEvent.type(searchInput, 'new keyword')
    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button'))

    // Wait for new search results to load
    const newMedicineNames = await screen.findAllByTestId('medicine-name')
    expect(newMedicineNames.length).greaterThan(0)
    expect(newMedicineNames[0]).not.equal(medicineNames[0])
  })
})
```

## expect

test success

Test Suites: 0 failed, 1 passed, 1 total Tests: 0 failed, 1 passed, 1 total